# how to commit a single query in a transaction

Tags: mysql, transactions

I'm debugging a complex complex stored procedure. I need to insert my prepared queries and their results in a debugging table but as whole of this procedure in enclosed between a BEGIN TRANSACTIN and COMMIT then nothing will be stored in my logging tables until COMMIT. So I can not find cause of problem if it raises an error and everything ROLLBacks.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately MySQL doesn't have autonomous transactions, but for log tables you can use the MyISAM storage engine. MyISAM doesn't have transactions, so in case of a rollback data inserted in a MyISAM log table isn't "lost".